# How to route to Home page after Login Validation in React using class components?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to validate login using a local json file, by fetching data using axios and setting state in class components. I'm unable to validate and route to the home page after login.

```
import { Component, React } from "react";
import bootstrap from "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import Navigation from "./Navigation";

var users;
var validUsername;
var validPassword;

export default class Login extends Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            users: [{
                id: "",
                role: "",
                username: "",
                password: "",
                status: "",
                security_question: "",
                security_answer: ""
            }],
            plans:  [
                {
                  id: "",
                  package: "",
                  status: "",
                  data_in_gb: "",
                  monthly_charge: "",
                  charge_after_limit: ""
                }
              ]
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get("../db.json").then(response => {
            this.setState({
                users: response.data.users,
                plans: response.data.plans
            });
            users = response.data.users;
        });
    }

    
    render() {
        return (
            <>
            <Navigation />

            <form>
                <table className="table text-center">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Login</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            Username
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <input type={"text"} onChange={validateUsername}></input>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            Password
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <input type={"password"} onChange={validatePassword}></input>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div className="text-center">
                    <Link to="/home"><button type={"submit"} onClick={validateLogin}>Login</button></Link>
                    <p id="error"></p>
                </div>
            </form>
            </>
        )
    }
}

function validateLogin() {
    if (validUsername && validPassword ) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals
        history.push("/home");
    }
}
var index = -1;
function validateUsername(event) {
    validUsername = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if (users[i].username == event.target.value) {
            index = i;
            validUsername = true;
        } 
    }
}

function validatePassword(event) {
        if (users[index].password == event.target.value) {
            validPassword = true;
        } else {
            validPassword = false;
        }
}
```

I'm trying to navigate user to home page after successful login validation, using local json file for login credentials. I'm unable to route to home page, as the link I provide to submit button directly lands me to the home page.

Comment: You are wrapping the button element with <Link> , remove the wrapping and try.

Answer (score 0):

Make a context and wrap the index.js. Use auth and add them at the route level

```
  <div className="App">
    <BrowserRouter>
      {authStatus && <Navbar />}
      <Routes>
          {!authStatus && <Route path="/*" element={<Login />} />}
            {authStatus && <>
          <Route path="/" element={<DashBoard />} />
          <Route path="/batch" element={<Batch />} />
          <Route path="/users" element={<Users />} />
          <Route path="/task" element={<Task />} />
        </>
        }
      </Routes>
   </BrowserRouter>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issues

You are directly wrapping the submit button with the `Link` component which immediately will navigate to `"/home"` upon being clicked.

## Solution

I suggest making the following changes.

1. Move the "Login" button's `onClick` handler to the `form` element's `onSubmit` handler and prevent the default for action from being taken.
2. Add an `onClick` handler to the `Link` component to prevent the link's default action from occurring, i.e. prevent immediately navigating.

```
import { Component, React } from "react";
import bootstrap from "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import Navigation from "./Navigation";

var users;
var validUsername;
var validPassword;

export default class Login extends Component {
  ...
    
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Navigation />

        <form onSubmit={validateLogin}>
          <table className="table text-center">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Login</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>Username</tr>
              <tr>
                <input type={"text"} onChange={validateUsername} />
              </tr>
              <tr>Password</tr>
              <tr>
                <input type={"password"} onChange={validatePassword} />
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div className="text-center">
            <Link to="/home" onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}>
              <button type="submit">Login</button>
            </Link>
            <p id="error"></p>
          </div>
        </form>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

```
function validateLogin(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (validUsername && validPassword ) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals
    history.push("/home");
  }
}

...
```